# Did I broke touchscreen or touchscreen and LCD?

Tags: touchscreen, broken-screen

I was trying to repair my broken touchscreen glass. I was going to use the touchscreen like that shown here, but every of them is transparent inside.
[image: transparent glass]

That would be absolutely OK, but after heating the touchscreen with hair-dryer and peeling it off it seems that there's not such black layer. The LCD screen is kinda silver.

Now take a look how my glass actually looks like.
[image: my broken glass]

I don't know if some polarization magic takes place here, but is that possible I peeled off some black layer from not only the touchscreen, digitizer, but from the LCD screen as well?

Answer (score 0):

Modern touchscreens consist of two parts:

1. **The digitizer**: This is transparent and detects the touch events.
2. **The LCD**: This is the screen and its *kinda silver*.

The digitizer and LCD are glued and are difficult to separate cleanly. It appears that you've removed a chunk of the LCD as well. The LCD and the digitizer are also sold as a single unit, glued together, so that they are easier to assemble.